# How to get contents of uploaded SVG file object

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a file input which require the user to upload an SVG file. What i want to do is, once the user uploaded the SVG file, my javascript or jquery will be able to get the svg file content as a string and then pass it to the server which is in PHP.

MY question is, how can i get content of the svg file as a string in javascript or jquery?

Example: i have a svg file named "star.svg". The user will upload this as a file.
Then, javascript or jquery will be able to get the content of star.svg and output as a string:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">    <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;"/>   
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG. </svg>
```

Comment: you might need to use AJAX to accomplish this

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert an SVG document (or an element and its children) to a string. This would do the whole document.

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString(document);
```

or replace document by a reference to an element to do an element and its children.